# Graphics programming resources

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I've been lately starting to learn how to draw computer graphics with openGL. I've been seeing a lot of words that I don't know. Eg. Processing pipe, shaders, shader language, graphic buffer,... I have absolutely no idea how graphic processors work, but I wasn't able to find any books which would explain it in a simple manner. Could you please suggest some resources on how computer graphics work?

Comment: They aren't all that "simple-mannered" topics.

Comment: I strongly suggest you work through Nicol Bolas's series of OpenGL tutorials. Not only do they explain OpenGL, but also the technical reasoning behind it and also a very thorough and well written history of realtime 3D graphics APIs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive Computer Graphics: A Top-Down Approach With Shader-Based OpenGL
Edward Angel & Dave Shreiner, 6th edition

It's the most recent version of a pretty good textbook that goes all the way from basics of vision and creating 3D images to modern GPU shaders. (You do need to know how to program.)